# Make Google Calendar API client library to call API directly with access token/refresh token

Tags: google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We have two solutions, one is a website, the other is a windows service. We write our own HTTP client class to redirect the users to go through the Google OAuth process from the website and get the Google Calendar access token/refresh token. Now we want the windows service to call the Google calendar API with the .net client library and access token/refresh token.

However, it appears that in order to use the client library, we have to go through the OAuth process again. Since we already get the access token/refresh token, I wonder whether it's possible to make the client library to call the Google Calendar API directly with the access token/refresh token.

I read through their doc and it appears that there's no similar examples: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet

Any proposals are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can make your own implementation of Idatastore and feed it the refresh token.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo. If I understand it correctly, Idatastore is a parameter to store the token returned by an OAuth process, not sure how to feed it...Do you have a code snippet for the Idatastore approach?

Comment: You can find some examples of alternate idatastores here https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/a11851d51f13addd70264d01be1928bf default used by the libary is filedatastore